# specific formula of a continuous map

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, dynamical-systems

Let $X= \mathbb{S}^1\cup \{(x, 0): -1<x<1\}$, where $\mathbb{S}^{1}=\{(x, y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: x^2+y^2=1\}$. Let $f:X\to X$ be a continuous map such that $f((-1, 0))= (-1, 0)$ and
$f((1, 0))= (1, 0)$. Also, for any $(x, y)\in \mathbb{S}^1\backslash \{(-1, 0),(1, 0)\}$, the first
coordinate of $f((x, y))$  is larger than $x$. Also, for any $(x, y)\in \{(x, 0): -1<x<1\}$,
the first coordinate of $f((x, y))$  is less than $x$. In my research I need to give the specific formula of $f$. Please help me to know it.

Comment: Can you find a continuous $f:[-1,1]\to[-1,1]$ such that $f(-1)=-1$, $f(1)=1$, and $f(x)<x$ for all $x\in(-1,1)$? Once you figure out how to do that, it’s not too hard to modify the idea to handle the circle. (Note that there are many functions that will work.)

Comment: You say you need "the specific formula", but there are uncountably many functions meeting all of your conditions. In addition to the uncountable ways of meeting your $<$ and $>$ coordinate conditions, each of the top, middle, and bottom paths has three choices as to which path it maps to. Those choices are independent, so there are 27 ways of making the choices.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to construct such a function; here’s one straightforward one to get this off the unanswered list.

Let $s:[-1,1]\to\Bbb R:x\mapsto\frac12(1-|x|)$; then $-1\le x-s(x)\le x+s(x)\le 1$ for any $x\in[-1,1]$, and $s(-1)=s(1)=0$. It’s easily checked that the function

$$f:X\to X:\langle x,y\rangle\mapsto\begin{cases}
\langle x-s(x),0\rangle,&\text{if }y=0\\
\left\langle x+s(x),\sqrt{1-\big(x+s(x)\big)^2}\right\rangle,&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

has the desired properties.